# Multiple regression model using scikit learn in python

Tags: python, pandas

when I am taking the independent variable 'age' ....reg.fit() showing an error like  " ['age'] not in index ".....can anyone please help me ?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
df=pd.read_csv('homeprices_multivariate.csv')
import math
median_bedrooms=math.floor(df.bedrooms.median())
df.bedrooms=df.bedrooms.fillna(median_bedrooms)
reg=linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(df[['area','bedrooms','age']],df.price)
```

then the error

> ['age'] not in index

Comment: please show the df columns

Comment: The error tells you exactly what the problem is, `'age'` isn't one of the columns in your dataframe. You can `print(df.columns)` to see what your columns are

Comment: @G.Anderson print(df.columns)....output is  Index(['area', 'bedrooms', 'age ', 'price'], dtype='object')

Comment: @BearBrown   print(df.columns)....output is   Index(['area', 'bedrooms', 'age ', 'price'], dtype='object')

Comment: There is a space after the e of age... it's `age ` not `age`

Comment: @BinyaminEven  omg !! it works ..Thank you very much...but why this space created automatically for only 'age'  why not for 'area,bedrooms and price' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strip the column names and it should work:

```
df.columns=[c.strip() for c in df.columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

The age column heading has an extra space in your data set.  Your last line should be changed to:

```
reg.fit(df[['area','bedrooms','age ']],df.price)
```